# CSS3 transition affects parent div

Tags: css, transition

I'm trying to find out why this CSS3 transition affects the parent div:

http://jsfiddle.net/BpUqt/5/

I'm trying to move an object up inside a div without changing the height of its parent div.

But what happens is that the height of the box shrinks by 1px each time the transition begins/ends (with or without border)

While I want to use three of these in a row my content beyond begins to jump up too if the user hovers over these items very quickly.

Setting an fixed height is not an option since I'm working on an responsive layout.

Comment: You mean it's jumpy in IE only. Never use IE as a reference for how things work. It's the worst browser on the planet.

Comment: I know. I hate IE, too. Neather did I use IE. But it's the same with Safari or Chrome, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: I don't see the problem in any other browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's a simple work-around. Simply add a negative margin and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/BpUqt/12/

Here's how it actually looks like (minimal version):

http://jsfiddle.net/sSjQt/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of animating margin (which means the box height needs to be recalculated, so rounding errors on partial pixels causes movement), use transforms.

Also, remember that IE10 has transitions, so use the ms prefix as well.

Have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/BpUqt/10/

Comment: IE10 won't be out for a year and no one will be able to use it unless they upgrade to Windows8.

Comment: This is actually a good idea but it leads to some more problems: Since I'm working on a responsive layout I would have to recalculate the margin every time. That aside, the circle keeps jumping in hover state. And the most wired thing is - and this actually should be another question - why does the font weight of the text change when you use the transform command in general? I've seen this a couple of times already. In the end, the recalculation seems to be the problem, yes. So still looking for a workaround though.

Comment: Ok, here's an idea: To get around that problem in a static layout you could position the circle absolute to the parent div and set a fixed height to the parent div. For a responsive solution the parent div would get an transaprent img inserted in the width and height of the circle. Beside another http request the problem would be solved then. What do you think?

Comment: Think I'd have to see a complete demo of what you are trying to do to work out what you mean.

Comment: To answer other comments, IE10 beta for Windows 7 will be out closer to final release. IE10 isn't a Win8 only browser. Also, IE9 has transforms already, just not transitions - you could easily use jQuery to do the animation there as well.

Comment: The font changes weight on older versions of Chrome (and maybe others) due to the way it renders things. It's fixed in newer versions.

Comment: @Rich Bradshaw I updated the fiddle once more. This is what I actually wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/sSjQt/